# Best way to convert Jackson to JDBC Recordset for SQL Server CRUD updates?

Tags: sql-server, json, jdbc, guice, jackson

I'm sucessfully sending JSON from the client using jQuery to the server which has Guice bindings to Jackson using bind:

```
        bind(MessageBodyReader.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        bind(MessageBodyWriter.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class)
```

Once I have my JSON object, I need to perform CRUD operations to update the database.  I can manually parse the JSON or build a JSON object for the getter; but it seems like there should be an automatic way to do this such as serializing to/from the recordset. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have POJOs to use (JSON to/from POJO), I would suggest looking at [jDBI](http://jdbi.org/) library for DB access. It adds convenience methods including data binding between POJOs and ResultSets (similar to how Jackson works between JSON and POJOs). It might even be possible to use Jackson to from JSON to java.util.Map, and jDBI from Map to JDBC objects (bind to statement etc).

If one wanted to do it, writing serializers/deserializers between JSON and ResultSet would be totally doable as well, and could be packaged as simple Jackson extension module.
I assume quite a few users would find this useful as well; but to my knowledge no such thing exists yet.